# Another table for warehouse or any other standard

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, inventory

there are three kind of transaction through which stock in or out from warehouse given below

1-pick list
2-return list
3-DA list

DA list contain information how much stock stock keeper purchase from a dealer (stock in)
Pick list are those the stock he gives to different sales man for sales(stock out)
return lists are those the stock not sales by a sales man and he return it to stock keeper (stock in)

the stock keeper wants these query must enable

1-can see previous list of all kinds (PL RL DA lists) by date, by sales man 
2-how much stock available in Warehouse

tables are below there

```
sku(id, name, type, category)
batch(sku_id, batch, price , date)
salesman(id, name)
transaction_type(type_id, transaction_name)
transaction_header(list_id , salesman_id, route )
transaction_detail(list_id, sku_id , Qty)
```

list id primary key contain prefix like da-34244 pl-453 rs-3432 on the basis it identify which type of list is

So the problem is how to update this warehouse table

```
warehouse(sku_id, qty , typeofsku)
```

the possibilities i suppose may be

when user enter list gives him a button on form are you k this is list and when user pres this button first enter the detail in transaction_detail and pick the qty from this table and get the qty from warehouse on the basis of list type add or subtract and then update warehouse.

is there are other efficient and good approach kindly suggest and give detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, every table should have a blind primary or clustering key.  A blind key is a key that has nothing to do with the underlying data.  A blind key is usually an auto-incrementing integer or long, or some other unique ID.

> List ID is a primary key that contains a prefix like da-34244 pl-453 rs-3432 which identifies what type of list it is.

You should never have combination fields like this in a data base column.  You should break the field up into a list code (da, pl, rs) and a number.  You combine the fields when you generate an output so the users see their familiar list ID.  I'm assuming these numbers are just incrementing integers.  Separating the list type from the list number in the database makes it easier to keep track of the numbers used.

> Query previous lists of all kinds (PL RS DA lists) by date, by sales man

You don't store a time stamp in any of your tables, so there's no way to query by date.  Plus, you need to decide whether the list type is stored as uppercase or lowercase in your database.  You've used list type in both lowercase and uppercase.

> Query how much stock available in Warehouse

You finally mention a warehouse table that has the quantity values you would need.

**Transactions**

Edited to add: Sometimes, you have to execute more than one SQL statement to complete a transaction.

You have a transactions header table, a transaction detail table and a warehouse table.

Assuming the transaction detail table is from a return list, which means we're adding the stock quantity back to the warehouse table.

Your program would have to perform the following SQL steps

- insert the information into a transaction header row.
- For each sku in the return list:

  - Insert the information into a transaction detail row.
  - Select the warehouse row with the same sku_id.
  - Add the quantity from the transaction detail row to the quantity of the warehouse row.  If this were a pick list, you would subtract the quantity of the transaction detail row from the quantity of the warehouse row.
  - Update the quantity on the warehouse row.
- Commit the database changes.

Either all of the above steps happen successfully, or none of the above steps happen successfully.  This is what's known as a transaction.  That's why you commit (or rollback) changes to a database.

The synchronization of a transaction is what keeps your stock quantities correct.  Imagine what would happen in a real warehouse if the transaction detail rows were written to the database, but the warehouse quantity wasn't updated.

And yes, you have to do all of the steps outlined above.  There is no shortcut.

Comment: i think Time stamp is necessary because user wants to view lists by Date also.

Comment: Sir the answer about warehouse table is not clear i want a mechanism through which warehouse table update the quantity. How this will implement is we take values from transaction_ detail table and check if this is return slip then it mean incoming stock in warehouse and we make a query first to get values of sku with quantity and then make addition to it and then insert new value in this table mean warehouse...? how update warehouse.......?

Comment: @Waleed Ehsan: Just as you described, which is why I didn't mention it in my answer.  You would use a programming language to execute multiple SQL statements in one transaction.  SQL UPDATE updates one or more columns in a table.

Comment: sir @Gilbert Le Balanc  you mean we have first make a statement that gets sku quantity from warehouse and store it in variable then another from transaction detail table and then add/subract with that stored variable and then insert result into warehouse table.